# Determining relationship to President Jefferson?

Tags: united-states, kinship-terminology

I am a little confused with determining the relationship status here:

My 4th Great Grandfather was the brother of Mary Branch. Mary is the Great Grandmother of Thomas Jefferson so the line is this:

- William Branch   sibling to Mary Branch
- son Elias,
- Grandson Michael,
- Great Grandson Walton,
- 2nd Great Grandson Allen,
- 3rd Great Granddaughter Jessie,
- 4th Great Granddaughter, Me.

Mary's line she married Thomas Jefferson Sr, they had:

- Thomas Jefferson Jr. son,
- Peter Jefferson grandson,
- President Thomas Jefferson Great grandson.

So am I a 4th cousin, 3 times removed to President Jefferson?

Answer (score 2):

I work it out this way:

- Wiliam and Mary are siblings
- Elias and Thomas Jr are 1st cousins
- Michael and Peter are 2nd cousns
- Walton and President are 3rd cousins

you are three generations below Walton i.e. three times removed.

Assuming the information that you provided is accurate, by my reckoning, that would make you a 3rd cousin 3 times removed from President Jefferson.